# Convert IP address from any base to any base in python

Tags: python, int, ip

So, this far i wrote this:

```
o_base = int(input("Enter origin base: "))
o_IP = input("Enter IP address: ")
#t_base = int(input("Enter target base (choose from"))

def to_decimal(number, base):
    result = 0
    for index, character in enumerate(number):
        result += int(character) * base ** index
    return result

def ip2bin():

    IP = ".".join(map(str,["{0:0b}".format(to_decimal(x,o_base)) for x in o_IP.split(".")]))
    return IP

print(ip2bin())
```

And I can convert from decimal to binary by setting b in {0:0**b**}, octal by **o** and hexadecimal by **x**. But i need to convert it from any base to any other (both specified from input)

Can you help to code this thing?

Comment: Start by using the `ipaddress` module to get the IP address as an integer: `int(ipaddress.IPv4Address('192.0.2.42')) == 3221226026`.

Comment: `int` can parse a base 2-base36 literal, but there is no built-in way to get an arbitrary base representation of an `int` object.